# Сумма квадратов значений массива

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть ли более универсальное решения для нахождения суммы квадратов всех элементов в массиве?

```js
var out = 0;

function squareSum(numbers){
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var res = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
    out += res;
    console.log(out);
  }
}



squareSum([1, 2, 2]);
```

Comment: а куда еще универсальнее?

Comment: @Grundy действительно), подвергаю критике свой код и сравниваю его с другими реализациями

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз уж вопрос (фактически) сводится к инспекции кода, то считаю необходимым прокомментировать каждую строчку исходного кода:

```
// Здесь вы определяете ГЛОБАЛЬНУЮ переменную, засоряя при этом глобальное пространство имен.
// В будущем это может привести к очень неочевидным проблемам при отладке.
var out = 0;

function squareSum(numbers){
    // Стоит отметить, что условие перехода к следующей итерации
    // цикла выполняется для КАЖДОГО его элемента. Это значит,
    // что имея массив из 10 тысяч элементов вы 10 тысяч раз выполните
    // numbers.length. Согласитесь, это не очень то эффективно (особенно
    // если учесть, что длина массива не меняется).
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // Переменная res - не нужна. Кроме того, получение элемента массива
        // занимает некоторое время, поэтому на больших массивах выполнять
        // эту операцию дважды - не лучшая идея.
        var res = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
        // Используя переменную из глобального контекста вы сломаете
        // любой другой код, который от нее зависит. Да, сейчас вы об
        // этом помните, но где гарантии, что вы (или ваш последователь)
        // не станет использовать эту же переменную где-то еще?
        out += res;
        // Эта конструкция тоже разрушает "чистоту" функции. 
        // Представьте, что вам нужно будет выкинуть все console.log
        // из кода. Что будете делать?
        console.log(out);
    }
}

// Ок, но функция, результат которой не используется - не нужна.
squareSum([1, 2, 2]);
```

Ну а теперь пример того, как **абсолютно** тоже самое (в том числе и вывод промежуточных значений в консоль) можно сделать лучше.

<sub>(Вариант со сменой подхода на функциональный я рассматривать не буду, так как это уже сделано в соседних ответах.)</sub>

```
function squareSum(numbers, logger) {
    var res = 0,
        // Если последний аргумент опущен, то заменяем реальную
        // функцию-логгер на заглушку, которая не будет делать ничего.
        log = (typeof logger === 'function') ? logger : function() {};

    for (var i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++) {
        res += Math.pow(numbers[i], 2);
        log(res);
    }

    return res;
}

var sum = squareSum([1, 2, 2], console.log);
```

Comment: прошу прошения, но современные браузеры разве не оптимизируют такие вещи? программисту всё равно нужно следить за этим? Стоит отметить, что условие перехода к следующей итерации
    // цикла выполняется для КАЖДОГО его элемента. Это значит,
    // что имея массив из 10 тысяч элементов вы 10 тысяч раз выполните
    // numbers.length. Согласитесь, это не очень то эффективно (особенно
    // если учесть, что длина массива не меняется).

Comment: @stas0k, В общем виде, вместо `i < arr.length` может быть любое вычисляемое выражение. А это значит, что оно действительно будет вычисляться каждый раз. Ну и каждое вычисление длины (учитывая, что массивы в js не имеют фиксированных размеров) требует лишних телодвижений от движка. Такие вещи лучше учитывать. А вообще, раз уж вопрос про код-ревью, то я постарался указать как можно больше _потенциально_ проблемных/не хороших вещей.

Comment: благодарю вас, советы действительно ценные, поэтому и отметил ваш ответ на вопрос, как ответ) . Илья Кантор в разговоре как-то упомянул, что сейчас движки подобные оптимизации научились делать и не вычисляют по тысячу раз длину массива в цикле, поэтому я не придал этому значения. спасибо Вам!

Comment: logger передавать в параметре, это бред. numbers.length - каждый раз вычисляться не будет, JS не так туп. Да и человек про алгоритм спрашивал помоему, а не о форматировании кода.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, про алгоритмы - есть другие ответы (о чем я в явном виде и сказал). Про логгер в качестве аргумента - в 99% случаев это лучше, чем потом судорожно выкусывать все вхождения `console.log`. (Заметьте, _ни в одном_ из соседних ответов нет вывода промежуточных результатов в консоль.) Ну и мой ответ не про _форматирование_ а про код-ревью. Я ставил целью **не изменить** логику и/или результат выполнения кода, а **привести** существующий код в приличное состояние.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, ну а что касается `numbers.length` вы не видите сути. Посмотрите на мой комментарий выше "_В общем виде, вместо `i < arr.length` может быть любое вычисляемое выражение_". Иными словами, там может быть любое трудоемкое выражение, зависящее только от исходного массива. Если есть шанс сэкономить на вычислении константного выражения - им надо пользоваться. Это из разряда best practice. Да, для длинны массива _некоторые_ движки JS могут проводить определенные оптимизации, но в случае с произвольным выражением - это не так.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, человек хотел "более универсальное" решение, именно его он и получил) Для сниппета в пару строчек выглядит страшновато, но как маленький кусочек железобетонного ынтырпрайз решения - самое то.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, так же добавлю что мир в котором приходится выкусывать консольлоги и js-движок устроен как страшный сон босха, еще существует. IE8< ему имя. Такое очень редко, но еще встречается в глубоком ынтырпрайзе.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev так писать нельзя, а человек это мог воспринять как рекомендацию к стилю кодинга. Поэтому минус от меня.

Comment: @Утка круто, ты бы ещё IE6 вспомнил. Да и есть хорошее правило все строчки console.log использовать только при отладке, иначе - удалять. Нужно логгирование в продакшене - для этого добавляют синглтон логгера, а передавать его в аргументах - отнюдь не изящно.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, ну ie6 мертв, да. Но ie8 еще изредка пошевеливается в корпоративном сегменте. И я знаю парней которые еще поддерживают IE7. И у них реально юзеры с ie7 есть. Живые. И бизнес готов платить им за то, чтобы эти юзеры чувствовали себя хорошо. А еще есть китайцы. Как у них сейчас не знаю, а года два назад у них ситуация с браузерами кардинально отличалась от общемировой в пользу ie.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, синглтон давным-давно антипаттерн. Если в jquery-лапше это еще простительно, то в серьезном backend js приложении (привет node.js) за такое надо бить по рукам.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, я не говорю что это изящно. Но подход вполне норм. Другое дело, что по мне это 95% вопрос вкуса а не кровавой необходимости. И да, я как-то потерял день своей жизни на отладку, потому что один персонаж заманкипатчил синглтон логгера.

Comment: 1. `.length` давно оптимизируется. 2. `console.log.bind(console)`, не? 3. Если консоль не в IE.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function squareSum(numbers){
  var result = 0;
  numbers.forEach(function(item) {
    result += Math.pow(item, 2);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log( squareSum([1, 2, 2]) );
```

В данном примере, проходим по массиву с помощью метода `forEach()`, каждый элемент массива `item` возводится в квадрат с помощью метода `Math.pow(число, степень)`.

> Метод `forEach()` выполняет указанную функцию один раз для каждого элемента в массиве.

[MDN Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> Метод Math.pow() возвращает основание, возведённое в степень показатель.

[MDN Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

Comment: Тогда уж надо использовать `reduce` вместо `forEach`

Answer (score 3):

Можно посчитать через map и reduce:

```js
function squareSum(numbers){
  return numbers.map(function (n) { return n * n; })
                .reduce(function (sum, n) { return sum + n; });
}

alert(squareSum([1, 2, 2]));
```

[Посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/tsroz28p/)

А вообще - что помешало вам загуглить эту распространенную задачу? Например, [здесь есть аж 4 варианта решения](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares#JavaScript).

Comment: в гугле я не могу получить обратную связь, что в моём коде не правильно и конечно надеюсь получить советы более опытных товарищей, хитрости разные приёмы программирования

Answer (score 2):

Используя метод `Math.hypot`, который возвращает квадратный корень суммы квадратов своих аргументов. Возведя результат в квадрат, получим искомую сумму.

```js
function squareSum() {
    return Math.pow(Math.hypot.apply(null, arguments[0]), 2);
}

console.log(squareSum([1, 2, 2]));
```

Comment: Думаю стоит указать, что функция `Math.hypot` есть далеко не везде

Comment: Зачем вы используете `arguments[0]` вместо нормального аргумента? Взяли и на пустом месте выключили оптимизацию...

Answer (score 1):

```js
function squareSum(numbers){
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){
    return (n*n) + sum;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(squareSum([1,2,2]));
```